# Как сделать сортировку списка по алфавиту

Tags: c++, файлы, сортировка

Как мне сделать сортировку в 3 файлах по алфавиту? Как выполнить сортировку по алфавиту используя фамилию студента, перед записью в файл. Т.е в файл должен записаться уже отсортированный список. [Пример кода](http://ideone.com/Xtg4g5).

Исходные данные:

- `student[i].Family` - Фамилия студента
- `student[i].Name` - Имя студента
- `student[i].Sex` - Пол
- `student[i].Date[0]` - число
- `student[i].Date[1]` - месяц
- `student[i].Date[2]` - год рождения
- `student[i].City` - город рождения

  ```
      case 2:

      char f4[20];
      FILE *z1;

      cout << "\nВведите имя файла для чтения: ";

      //fscanf(v, "%d", &m); 
      cin >> f4;

      z1 = fopen(f4, "r");
      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
          fscanf(z1, "%s%s%s%d%d%d%s", &student[i].Family, &student[i].Name, &student[i].Sex, &student[i].Date[0], &student[i].Date[1], &student[i].Date[2], &student[i].City);
      cout << "\nЧтение из файла " << f4 << ":\n";
      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
          cout << student[i].Family << " " << student[i].Name << " " << student[i].Sex << " " << student[i].Date[0] << "." << student[i].Date[1] << "." << student[i].Date[2] << " " << student[i].City << "\n";






      cout << "File name? ";
      char girls[50];
      cin.getline(girls, 50);
      f = fopen("girls.txt", "a+");
      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
          if (strcmp(student[i].Sex, "Female") == 0)
          {
              student[i].Show();
          }

      //сортировка по алфавиту это то что я сам сейчас попробовал но это не работает походу
      while (a == 1)
      {
          a = 0;
          for (int i = 0; i<N - 1; i++){
              if (strcmp(student[i].Family, student[i + 1].Family)>0)
              {

                  strcpy(tmp, student[i].Family);
                  strcpy(student[i].Family, student[i + 1].Family);
                  strcpy(student[i + 1].Family, tmp);
                  /*strcpy(tmp, fr[i].dolgnost);
                  strcpy(fr[i].dolgnost, fr[i + 1].dolgnost);
                  strcpy(fr[i + 1].dolgnost, tmp);
                  tmp1 = fr[i].stag;
                  fr[i].stag = fr[i + 1].stag;
                  fr[i + 1].stag = tmp1;*/
                  a = 1;
              }
          }
      }// вот до этого момента новое.
      fclose(f); //С помощью цикла показываем всех девочек.
      system("pause");
      break;
  ```

Comment: Сортировать допустим по фамилии, только я не понимаю как это сделать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вопрос. Что конкретно вы не понимаете: как открыть поток на чтение, как считать структуру student из потока, как поместить считанные структуры в вектор, как отсортировать вектор используя свою функцию сравнения, как написть функцию сравнения для student, которая будет сравнивать по фамилии, как записать данные обратно в файл?

Comment: @dzhioev Как выполнить сортировку по алфавиту используя фамилию студента, перед записью в файл. Т.е в файл должен записаться уже отсортированный список

Comment: @BalinMisha если у Вас проблема с сортировкой то вопрос лучше переименовать например в "Как сделать сортировку списка" и убрать лишнее из вопроса, то что не касается сортировки

Comment: @Bald56rus ага, спасибо. Буду ждать, мб кто-нибудь подскажет

Comment: посмотрите в сторону функции std::sort()

Comment: @Balin Misha Покажите, в какой структуре у вас хранятся данные., которые вы собираетесь отсортировать.

Comment: @Arkady спасибо разобрался strcpy взял

Comment: @VladfromMoscow спасибо разобрался strcpy взял

Answer (score 1):

в комментариях уже упоминали, что можно использовать коллекцию и функцию sort().
Создать коллекцию. Заполнить список значениями.

```
 list<Student> lines;
```

Переопределить оператор больше (или меньше) для вашей структуры.

```
bool Student::operator < (const Student& rhs) const
{
    return ...
}
```

Затем применять функцию sort().

```
lines.sort();
```

---

Также можно сравнивать коды букв из [ASCII](http://book.itep.ru/10/ascii.htm).

Вот пример простенькой программки, использующей коды символов:

```
char Name1 [5]={'B','C','D','Z','Y'};
char Name2 [5]={'A','c','E','T','k'};
for(int i =0 ; i<5;i++){
    cout<<Name1[i]-Name2[i]<<" ";
}
```

На выходе:

```
1 -32 -1 6 -18
```

В вашем же случае необходимо применить обычный метод сортировки, чтобы в начале списка была фамилия, имеющая наименьший код первого символа.

Comment: Спасибо вам, вы правильно поняли. Но это не то .

Comment: @BalinMisha, А чем именно не подходит метод? Может кого-то другого ответ на этот вопрос подтолкнет на правильный ответ.